# Developer machine spec for windows

Tags: windows, performance, visual-studio-2010, developer-machine

Can anyone suggest a spec for a developer machine for Windows 7 OS, visual studio 2010?
Looking for what people have regarding RAM, Core, CPU, Hard drive etc
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My development workstation:

- 8GB RAM (go for 2x4GB, so you can upgrade to 16GB in the future)
- 80GB SSD (Intel X25 M2, there are better ones out now)
- 1TB regular hard drive for storage and VMs
- Dell U2311h 1920x1080 IPS panel for primary monitor (can also do portrait mode, which is great for programming)
- Daewoo M-17X 1280x1024 TN panel for secondary monitor (documentation, browser, terminals go here).
- Microsoft Wired 3000 keyboard (pretty good but not perfect)
- Logitech G5 mouse (excellent but pricey - left-over from when I used to game).
- A standard set of speakers and a logitech webcam for teleconferences.
- Mouse pad and keyboard pad with wrist rests (necessary for long coding sessions).
- Seasonic S12 430W PSU (silent, efficient and trustworthy)

Notice how I didn't mention a CPU? That's because it's secondary to the above. I'm using a 3.2GHz Core 2 that I plan to upgrade to a quadcore at some point soon. Either AMD or Intel will be fine (Intel is faster but AMD is significantly cheaper right now - your choice!)

Video card: will you be doing 3d games? If not, go for the second or third cheapest AMD 6xx0 card you can find (why AMD? Because they are guaranteed to support 3 monitors and their VGA outputs are generally cleaner than Nvidia ones. Seriously, you never know when you might need that!) Integrated video will work, too, in a pinch, but you'll be limited to at most 1 digital out and 1 awful VGA out at best.

For 3d, go for a mid-high end video card around $150-$300. Either manufacturer is fine, although AMD 6xx0 appears to be slightly better value for money than Nvidia 5x0 in most price points in the last few reviews I checked. If you also care about GPGPU or 3d modeling, you'll find better support on the Nvidia side of the fence.

One final word of advice: invest in a good PSU (Seasonic or Corsair are fine). Also take a look at noise reviews for the components you'll be choosing - and avoid extremely noisy components at all costs! You want to work, not hear a dustblower working.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on the sort of development and debugging you'll be doing. Some development is little more taxing than editing and web browsing.  Other development is impeded by CPU and storage bottlenecks every time you hit F5.

In general though, you'll want a SSD, not a mechanical hard drive and plenty of RAM.

Don't undervalue your display, keyboard and mouse.  Spend money on these first, then think about CPU and GPU.